# Get map from two list having similar object ID

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to java stream API.
I have 2 lists, and if both their internal object ID matches wants to put some attributes to MAP.
Below is the implementation.

```
List<LookupMstEntity> examTypeDetails; //This list contains values init.
List<MarksMstEntity> marksDetailList;  //This list contains values init.

//FYI above entities have lombok setter, getter, equals & hashcode.

Map<Long, Integer> marksDetailMap = new HashMap<>();

//need below implementation to changed using java 8.
for (LookupMstEntity examType : examTypeDetails) {
    for (MarksMstEntity marks : marksDetailList) {
        if (examType.getLookupId() == marks.getExamTypeId())
            marksDetailMap.put(examType.getLookupId(), marks.getMarks());
    }
}
```

Comment: Some operations just aren't made for streams. Look at the complexity of below answers. Not worth converting a perfectly readable code to stream pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a set of lookupIds `Set<Long> ids` helps you to throw away duplicate values and to get rid of unnecessary checks.

Then you can filter `marksDetailList` accordingly with `examTypeId` values:

`filter(m -> ids.contains(m.getExamTypeId()))`

HashSet `contains()` method has constant time complexity O(1).

Try this:

```
Set<Long> ids = examTypeDetails.stream().map(LookupMstEntity::getLookupId)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

Map<Long, Integer> marksDetailMap = marksDetailList.stream().filter(m -> ids.contains(m.getExamTypeId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(MarksMstEntity::getExamTypeId, MarksMstEntity::getMarks));
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are looking for these with equal ID, it doesn't matter which ID you use then. I suggest you to start streaming the `marksDetailList` first since you need its `getMarks()`. The filtering method searches if there is a match  in IDs. If so, collect the required key-values to the map.

```
Map<Long, Integer> marksDetailMap = marksDetailList.stream() // List<MarksMstEntity>
    .filter(mark -> examTypeDetails.stream()                 // filtered those where ...
        .map(LookupMstEntity::getLookupId)                   // ... the lookupId
        .anyMatch(id -> id == mark.getExamTypeId()))         // ... is present in the list
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(                               // collected to Map ...
        MarksMstEntity::getExamTypeId,                       // ... with ID as a key
        MarksMstEntity::getMarks));                          // ... and marks as a value
```

The `.map(..).anyMatch(..)` can be shrink into one:

```
.anyMatch(exam -> exam.getLookupId() == mark.getExamTypeId())
```

As stated in the comments, I'd rather go for the  for-each iteration as you have already used for sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

An observation:

First, your resultant map indicates that there can only be one match for ID types (otherwise  you would have duplicate keys and the value would need to be a `List` or some other way of merging duplicate keys, not an `Integer`.   So when you find the first one and insert it in the map, break out of the inner loop.

```
for (LookupMstEntity examType : examTypeDetails) {  
    for (MarksMstEntity marks : marksDetailList) {
        if (examType.getLookupId() == marks.getExamTypeId()) {
                marksDetailMap.put(examType.getLookupId(),
                            marks.getMarks());
                // no need to keep on searching for this ID
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Also if your two classes were related by a parent class or a shared interface that had access to to the `id`, and the two classes were considered `equal` based on that `id`, then you could do something similar to this.

```
for (LookupMstEntity examType : examTypeDetails) {
    int index = marksDetailList.indexOf(examType);
    if (index > 0) {
            marksDetailMap.put(examType.getLookupId(),
                    marksDetaiList.get(index).getMarks());
    }
}
```

Of course the burden of locating the index is still there but it is now under the hood and you are relieved of that responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `O(N)` time complexity using `HashMap`, first convert two lists into `Map<Integer, LookupMstEntity>` and `Map<Integer, MarksMstEntity>` with id as key

```
Map<Integer, LookupMstEntity> examTypes = examTypeDetails.stream()
                                          .collect(Collectors.toMap(LookupMstEntity::getLookupId, 
                                                         Function.identity())  //make sure you don't have any duplicate LookupMstEntity objects with same id

Map<Integer, MarksMstEntity> marks = marksDetailList.stream()
                                          .collect(Collectors.toMap(MarksMstEntity::getExamTypeId, 
                                                         Function.identity())   // make sure there are no duplicates
```

And then stream the `examTypes` map and then collect into map if `MarksMstEntity` exists with same id in `marks` map

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result = examTypes.entrySet()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(entry->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, MarksMstEntity>(entry.getKey(), marks.get(entry.getKey())))
                                        .filter(entry->entry.getValue()!=null)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```